# Google Login problems

Tags: login, application-development, login-screen

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWmSv.png)I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS aarch64 on my PI400 and really liking it, however when i try to log my Google account in Settings/Online Accounts I get the attached.

It's not urgent, just annoying.  Any ideas?

I've tried updating and upgrading, nothing seems to work

Comment: There is nothing attached.

Answer (score 0):

**INSTALL Linux Kernel 5.19 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**
**Kernel 5.19 more better and faster than Kernel 5.15**
Download Kernel 5.19 =

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/amd64/linux-modules-5.19.0-051900-generic_5.19.0-051900.202207312230_amd64.deb
```

Source = [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19/)

Now, Install All =

```
sudo apt install ./linux-headers-5.19.0*.deb ./linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0*.deb ./linux-modules-5.19.0*.deb
```

Check Kernel Version =

```
uname -r
```

Output New Kernel 5.19 =

**5.19.0-051900-generic**

Now, Restart your Computer

REMOVE Kernel 5.15 from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS =

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.15.0* linux-modules-5.15.0* linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0*

sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out tonight!

Comment: Tried it,  came back with:  The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
                                             Depends: libelf1:amd64 (>= 0.144) but it is not installable
                                             Depends: libssl3:amd64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
                                             Depends: zlib1g:amd64 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.